# One-to-many spatial join with results in one row in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, spatial-join, overlapping-features, one-to-many

I have two feature Datasets. Both are Polygons. *'Dataset A'* has very big Areas and *'Dataset B'* just small ones. Now, *'Dataset B'* still overlaps in 2 or 3 Zones from *'Dataset A'*.

I want to perform a spatial join and put the result comma separated in just one row like this:

```
Zone_ID_A  |  Zone_ID_B 
   1       |   2,3
   2       |   2,4
   3       |   5
   4       |   1,6
```

I know this is possible with ArcMap but i could not figure out a way to do this in QGIS, any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a possibility of using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume there are two polygon layers: *'Layer_A'* (brown) and *'Layer_B'* (green) respectively, see image below.

[image: example]

With the following query, it is possible *to perform a spatial join and put the result comma separated in just one row*.

```sql
SELECT
    a.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.info) AS concat_b_info
FROM
    "Layer_A" AS a,
    "Layer_B" AS b
WHERE
    ST_INTERSECTS(a.geometry, b.geometry)
GROUP BY
    a.id
```

The output Virtual Layer will look like

[image: result]

If all features from the *'Layer_A'* should be involved in the final output i.e. where there is no intersection, please use the following query:

```sql
SELECT
    a.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.info) AS concat_b_info
FROM
    "Layer_A" AS a
LEFT JOIN
    "Layer_B" AS b
        ON ST_INTERSECTS(a.geometry, b.geometry)
GROUP BY
    a.id
```

---

**References:**

- [SQLite GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group_concat/)

Comment: Thank you Taras! That is an interesting way i did not think about. I just Posted another answer with the solution i came up

Answer (score 4):

Alright I figured out a way.

First I did [a spatial join](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location) like you would normal do with the one-to-many option.

Then I downloaded the Plugin ["Dissolve with stats"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DissolveWithStats/). Here I dissolved the `"Zone_ID_A"` and choose the option *"uniquification"* at the field `"Zone_ID_B"`. The Ouput was exactly what I wanted and descriped in the Original Post.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you may try the solution offered in this article ["Summary Aggregate and Spatial Filters in QGIS"](https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/04/12/summary-aggregation-qgis/). So, the expression in the Field Calculator will look like this:

```py
aggregate(
  layer:='Layer_B',
  aggregate:='concatenate',
  expression:="info",
  concatenator:=',',
  filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent))
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

An up-to-date approach is to use one of the [**overlay**](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core) functions e.g. the [`overlay_intersects()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#overlay-intersects) together with [`array_to_string()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#array-to-string).

This expression in the Field Calculator:

```
array_to_string(overlay_intersects('test', "info"))
```

will return an array represented as a string of expression-based results for the features in the target layer (*'test'*) intersected by the current feature, see the `"result"` field.

[image: result]