# Retrieving attributes from multiple polygons intersecting a given zone (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, intersection, spatial-join

I am trying to find a way to display relevant information for a given zone based on all the layers that it intersects.
For example, I'm studying five zones and I'd like to know for each of them which type of soil can be found within their boundaries.

I have tried to "join features by location" but I end up with multiple features when different type of soils are present in the area. This is not ideal because I'll have to repeat the process for many other layers (soil, geology, hydrography, ...)

In the image below for example, I would need to know which colors can be found within the red dotted area (yellow, blue, dark green and light green). It doesn't necessarily need to be stored as attributes, if I can have a .txt file with the info that's also fine.

[image]

Comment: Here is a [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/371067/84870) using virtual layers

Answer (score 6):

you can use the field calculator with the `aggregate` function for that task. The expression to collect information on your soil layer (where `type` is the fieldname in soil which will be aggregated) into a new column in the zones layer would be like the following:

```
aggregate(layer:='soil',
aggregate:='concatenate',
expression:="type",
filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent)),
concatenator:=',')
```

[image]