# Intersect without duplication (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, intersection, duplication

In QGIS 3.16, I have a layer of polygons corresponding to particular ecological habitat zones.  I'd like to perform a series of intersections in order to add information to each polygon as to where it is located, for example: what town it is in, what parcel, what catchment/drainage basin, what protected area (and several more).

The issue is that of course, many of my habitat polygons cross administrative and hydrological borders.  So if I intersect my layer1 with a layer containing town borders, the resulting intersection layer will duplicate each cross-border polygon, creating a separate entry for each town that the habitat polygon overlaps.

I'd like to avoid this duplication, or at least come up with a post-intersection trick to collapse the duplicates.  What I would want, ideally, would be a way to concatenate multiple towns (or basins, or protected areas) in the same field.  For example:

- [Habitat name]-[Town]
- Pond1         - Arlington, Lexington
- Bog1          - Lincoln
- Pond2         - Lincoln, Lexington

I've not found this trick yet.

Comment: [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370996/spatial-query-to-return-multiple-values/371067#371067) is a similar question with a solution using a virtual layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use QGIS expressions with the function `overlay_intersects( )`, [available since QGIS 3.16](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core). Set the field type to string as the output will be formatted as text:

```
array_to_string (
    overlay_intersects( 
        'polygon2', 
        $id
    )
)
```

*Screenshot: on the blue `polygon1`, create a new attribute, refering to the intersecting orange `polygon2` features. As you see in the preview of the expression editor at the bottom, the output will be `1,2,3`, thus the id of the three orange polygons the blue one intersects:*
[image]

Comment: Thank you Babel. This is working to give me the IDs of the relevant polygons -- but I'm afraid I'm not sure how to specify the field I want to visualize (Town Name, etc).  When I attempt to specify a field, I am only given the options for the fields in the current layer, and not another layer.  I am sure there is an SQL way to specify layer-->field...  do you know how this is accomplished?

Comment: Replace `$id` with the name of the field, like `"town_name"` - or even without quotes: `town_name`. This will return a list of the names contained in that field. Be sure to make the new field you create this way long enough so that names are not cut off.

Comment: Excellent! I had tried it before but after the $ sign, naturally with no luck...   Is there a way to add a space after the comma between names?  Right now it shows up as (for example) "Lincoln,Lexington" and I would prefer "Lincoln, Lexington".

Comment: Just replace the comma by a comma+space by adding to the expression a replace function: `replace( [array], ',', ', ' )` - instead of `[array]`, insert the whole expression from above. You could also change the field you already created: `replace( fieldname, ',', ', ' )` and change `fieldname` to the name of your field.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply -- this was exactly what I needed, Babel.  Thanks very much for the helpful and clear explanation.