# Concatenating names of the districts and the numbers of the sections in the polygonal layer of streets based on intersection

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, overlapping-features, one-to-many

[image]In QGIS 3.14 I want for a layer with street contours (polygons) to record the names of the areas through which the street passes and the numbers of cadastral plots through which it passes.

If a street intersects several objects, their names must be written in one field after a comma. How do I solve this problem?

[image]
if the area of the area falling into the boundaries of the street is less than the specified value, then its name is not taken into account

[image]

Comment: Hi Ivan, it is a bit unclear what you're asking. You seem to have a solution, which you don't present, and then ask for a more efficient one. How should we decide, if our solution is more efficient than yours? Or are you asking "how do I do this"? Both possible questions lack details, e.g. your existing solution, your data structure, some example data, and an example of your desired output.

Comment: Hi Erik, I edited my question

Comment: Thank you! But this is only the first part of the task. I need to add
conditions - if the area of the area falling into the boundaries of the street is less than the specified value, then its name is not taken into account

Comment: Please accept the answer that I posted if it solves your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend the query in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/354203/99589) with an *"area"*-rule, i.e. consider value only if the intersection is more than a certain value, then consider a slightly adjusted query:

```sql
SELECT a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(b.info) AS concat_b_info
FROM "Layer_B" AS b, "Layer_A" As a
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(a.geometry, b.geometry)
      AND ST_AREA(ST_INTERSECTION(a.geometry, b.geometry)) > 80000000
GROUP BY a.id
```

Or consider in the Field Calculator the following expression:

```py
aggregate(
  layer:='Layer_B',
  aggregate:='concatenate',
  expression:="info",
  concatenator:=',',
  filter:=(intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent)) AND area(intersection($geometry,geometry(@parent))) > 80000000)
)
```

Keep in mind that [`'area'`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#geometry-functions)-function

> Returns the area of a geometry polygon object. Calculations are always
> planimetric in the Spatial Reference System (SRS) of this geometry,
> and the units of the returned area will match the units for the SRS.
> This differs from the calculations performed by the $area function,
> which will perform ellipsoidal calculations based on the project's
> ellipsoid and area unit settings.

When areas of the overlapping features have to be additionally calculated, use this

```sql
SELECT a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(b.info) AS concat_b_info,
            GROUP_CONCAT(round(ST_AREA(ST_INTERSECTION(a.geometry, b.geometry)), 4)) AS a_b_areas
            -- GROUP_CONCAT(round(ST_AREA(b.geometry), 4)) AS b_areas
FROM "Layer_B" AS b, "Layer_A" As a
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(a.geometry, b.geometry)
      AND ST_AREA(ST_INTERSECTION(a.geometry, b.geometry)) > 80000000
GROUP BY a.id
```

or in the Field Calculator with a new field for area values:

```py
aggregate(
  layer:='Layer_B',
  aggregate:='concatenate',
  expression:=to_string(round(area(intersection($geometry,geometry(@parent))),4)),
  # expression:=to_string(round(area($geometry),4)),
  concatenator:=',',
  filter:=(intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent)) AND area(intersection($geometry,geometry(@parent))) > 80000000)
)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! And what function should I use in the field calculator to write the areas of incoming areas over a comma? Or their sum.
Thank you!

Comment: Taras,two options are possible - the sum of the areas of the crossing parts or the values ​ ​ of the areas of the crossing parts by a comma.

Comment: How to write this one "Full areas use (GROUP_CONCAT(ST_AREA(b.geometry))) or (GROUP_CONCAT(ST_AREA(ST_INTERSECTION(a.geometry, b.geometry))))"  in the field calculator?