# Counting points in polygon and printing out each placing

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, spatial-join, point-in-polygon, one-to-many

Here is my sample table for further description:

I have a original **point** layer:

| ID | Name | X(latitude) | Y(longtitude) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | Dog | A | 1 |
| ID2 | Cat | A | 1 |
| ID3 | Bird | B | 1 |
| ID4 | Cat | A | 2 |
| ID5 | Cat | B | 1 |
| ID6 | Dog | A | 1 |

Those points are inside a **grid** layer, lets say 2x2 for instance, and the points are inside the grid. I'll try my best to demonstrate it in the follow table:

| - | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **. . .** (Three points, which are ID1, ID2, ID6) | **. .** (ID3, ID5) |
| 2 | **.** (ID4) | (NULL) |

Next, I use the count_points_in_polygon function and create a new layer, which by default adds a column `"NUM_POINT"`.

| Grid_ID | NUM_POINT |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 3 |
| A2 | 2 |
| B1 | 1 |
| B2 | 0 |

But what I actually want is a table that shows which `"Name"`s are in each polygon, like the following table shows. How to implement it?

[image: correct table]

The closest method I found is a guide from https://cornell-gis.github.io/gis-cookbook/qgis/count-multivalues, but it's still slightly different.

Comment: This seems to be an issue for [aggregate](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=aggregate#aggregates-functions).

Comment: I'll try to do some research in aggregate, any more suggestion? thanks

Comment: Suggestions... be prepared for frustration. I find `aggregate` hard to master.

Comment: On the german fossgis conference 2020 I've made a workshop on the aggregate function, there is still an animated gif showing how to proceed: https://files.wheregroup.com/index.php/s/ysPjBt74pmD5qQp may be that helps...

Comment: IMHO the most intuitive approach is the ["Join attributes by location (summary)"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location-summary), here is a tutorial: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/performing_spatial_joins.html#performing-spatial-joins-qgis3. Also you may check https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305165/calculating-point-layer-values-within-polygon-features-in-qgis-2 with `GROUP_CONCAT`, more details here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354187/one-to-many-spatial-join-with-results-in-one-row

Answer (score 4):

You can create a virtual field in the Field calculator for the grid layer and fill it with

```
aggregate(layer:='Your pointlayername',
          aggregate:='concatenate',
          expression:=to_string(attributes()['attributenameofpointlayer']),
          filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent)),
          concatenator:=','
          )
```

You may need to transform coordinates with function [`transform()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=aggregate#transform) if grid (polygon) and coordinates points do not match due to difference for the projection

You can find a link to a minimum QGIS project demo https://labs.webgeodatavore.com/partage/demo-aggregate-expression-points-in-grid.zip

Comment: Oh no I fr$aking did it! but in my case I've changed the code into concatenate_unique for a cleaner result.  Very, very appriciated!

Answer (score 4):

Starting from QGIS 3.16 it is possible to use the [`overlay_*`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=aggregate#overlay-contains) functions and therefore the expression to be used:

```
array_to_string(overlay_contains('Your pointlayername',"name"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but how can I add a "unique" to the code since most the point names are the same.

Comment: @Cookie array_to_string (array_distinct (overlay_contains('punti',"id"))), using array_distinct

Answer (score 1):

I would take a little bit different approach.

1. Vector -> Data management tools -> Join attributes by location

   - set your polygon layer (grid layer) as a Base layer and point layer as a Join layer
   - set Geometric predicate to Intersects
   - For Fields to add section choose Name field (from your point layer)

   As a result you will get a layer with as many rows as you have intersecting points with your polygons. At one row you see the information regarding your polygon object + the name of the point object it intersects with (e.g. if grid A1 contains 3 points, grid A1's field info will show up for three rows each time associated with different point name).
2. Create new fields for this result layer.

   2.1 The numerical field telling you the number of points in each polygon with

   ```
   count("grid_id", group_by:="grid_id")
   ```

   2.2 The list of the point layer names including in each grid with

   ```
   concatenate_unique("point_name", group_by:="grid_id", concatenator:=' ,')
   ```
3. Delete additional fields and rows to get the desired kind of table

Comment: This probably is the closest answer for what I desired, but it came up with multiple identical IDs in step 2.1, is there anyway to fix this?
Here's a quick sample

Comment: https://imgur.com/ECWFqD1

Comment: Just create new IDs e.g. with attribute table's Quick field calculation bar by setting ID = @row_number?