# Creating relations many to one in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, spatial-join, overlapping-features, many-to-one

I have a vector layer with polygons A, and the second with polygons B. Polygons A includes/are intersected by several polygons B.

I want to join the data (just names of polygons) from polygons B to polygons A (in result polygon A get a field with all names of polygons B witch are intersected by them).

Polygons B are not a 100%-correct. Actually borders of B should be drawn in the same line of A border, but they are not in many of cases.

Is there any way to tell QGIS to join all of intersected B to one A but only if specified minimum %area of B is in A?

The last (I hope) question - output data A includes repeated data (ex. screen).

How could I get rid of duplicates?

[image]

Comment: You must have a unique ID (it's more easier) for your layers and go to the menu Vector > Geoprocessing > Intersects. So you'll have your polygon A layer with B attributes. You can after update your polygon A layer with a join on unique ID.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [One-to-many spatial join with results in one row](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354187/one-to-many-spatial-join-with-results-in-one-row)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an extension to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/354203/99589).

In QGIS I can suggest using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume there are two polygon layers `'grid_test2'` (green) and `'grid_test'` (red) respectively, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible to achieve the result, i.e. to join all unique `"ID"`s of intersected `'grid_test'` to one `'grid_test2'` but only if specified minimum of `'grid_test'` is in `'grid_test2'`.

```sql
SELECT a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.id) AS b_ids
FROM "grid_test2" AS a
LEFT JOIN "grid_test" AS b ON st_area(st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry)) > 0.1
GROUP BY a.id
```

In the example above I eluded the cell with `"ID" = 3` from the `'grid_test'` layer, where the intersection area is not large enough (this condition does it `st_area(st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry)) > 0.1`), see image below.

[image: area]

The output Virtual Layer will look like as following

[image: result]

---

As an alternative you may try the solution offered in this article ["Summary Aggregate and Spatial Filters in QGIS"](https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/04/12/summary-aggregation-qgis/). So, the expression in the Field Calculator for above example will look like:

```py
aggregate(layer:='grid_test',
        aggregate:='concatenate_unique',
        expression:=to_string("id"),
        concatenator:=',',
        filter:=area(intersection($geometry,geometry(@parent)))>0.1
        )
```