# Joining all atrributes of one column in point-layer like number in multiple columns of a polygon-layer like number_1, number_2 etc. in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, field-calculator, attribute-joins, intersect

I got a point-layer ***Points*** where all points lying exactly on the vertexes of the polygons of a polygon-layer ***Polygons***.

How do I join all numbers of the point-layer to the polygon-layer?

All algorithms I used didn't really work (NNjoin, MMQGIS, select attributes by location etc.).

What I need is to bring the column ***Nr*** into multiple columns of the polygon-layer like Nr_1, Nr_2, Nr_3, Nr_4. To bring it into one column like including a separator would also work.

I'm running QGIS 3.16.3.

[image]

Comment: For all results in 1 column, see this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370996/spatial-query-to-return-multiple-values/371067#371067)

Comment: Also [1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354187/one-to-many-spatial-join-with-results-in-one-row) and [2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/407639/creating-relations-many-to-one-in-qgis/407689#407689)

Comment: @Taras: In my case the output is for all three polygons the same: '1194,196,1195,193,1193,1196,11'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want e.g. by running custom PyQGIS script in QGIS's Python console. First, open attribute table of the polygon layer and create a new column to it (named here as ListOfNrs). Second, go to Python console (Ctrl+Alt+P), open script editor, paste the following code in it and press the green triangle to execute the script.

```py
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()
layers = mapcanvas.layers()

# Assuming that first layer contains point data
# and second layer contains polygon data

for a in layers[1].getFeatures():
    temp = list()
    prov = layers[1].dataProvider()
    targetfield = layers[1].fields().lookupField('ListOfNrs')
    for b in layers[0].getFeatures():
        if a.geometry().intersects(b.geometry()):
            temp.append(b["Nr"])
    temp2 = ",".join(temp)
    atts = {targetfield: temp2}
    # call changeAttributeValues(), pass feature id and attribute dictionary
    prov.changeAttributeValues({a.id(): atts})
```

Comment: it works well if both columns 'Nr' in Layer "Points" and 'ListOfNrs' in Layer "Polygons" are strings. Is there a possibility to extend the code by a buffer if the any point is not exactly on the vertex of a polygon? THX for great help by now